# Unable to change membership

Tags: civimember

I am not able to change a membership.
Version 5.34.0
Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit a membership
2. Change e.g. the end date
3. Save the membership.

A popup message appears saying the membership change has been carried out with the date given. However, the change is not recorded.
This happens with every change.

[image]

Comment: This happens after upgrading to 5.34.0 from 5.33.2.

Answer (score 2):

Note this is also tracked in gitlab https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/membership/-/issues/34